# Django unique_for_date with models.DateField(editable=False)

Tags: django, validation, unique-constraint

Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.unique_for_date) says:

> If any `unique_for_date` constraint involves fields that are not part of
> a `ModelForm` (for example, if one of the fields is listed in `exclude` or
> has `editable=False`), `Model.validate_unique()` will skip validation for
> that particular constraint.

The model below sets `unique_for_date` for a `DateField` with `editable=False`, as mentioned above.

Based on the excerpt from the documentation above, I would expect the `unique_for_date` constraint to be skipped during validation.

However, the test below passes, showing that `Model.validate_unique()` *does* raise a `ValidationError` due to `unique_for_date` (using Django 3.0).

What am I missing?

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.test import TransactionTestCase


class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique_for_date='date')
    date = models.DateField(editable=False)


class MyModelTests(TransactionTestCase):
    def test_name_unique_for_date(self):
        name = 'bird'
        today = timezone.now().date()
        MyModel.objects.create(name=name, date=today)
        with self.assertRaises(ValidationError) as a:
            MyModel(name=name, date=today).validate_unique()
        self.assertIn('Name must be unique for Date date.', a.exception.messages)
```

Comment: You don't use a `ModelForm` here, hence the cleaning can be done on *all* objects.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Thanks for pointing that out. So the documentation says "`Model.validate_unique()` will skip validation for that particular constraint", but it is actually `BaseModelForm.validate_unique()` that causes the constraint to be skipped. `Model.validate_unique()` will not skip the constraint unless we explicitly set `exclude=['date']`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @WillemVanOnsem's comment above:

Although the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.unique_for_date) says

> ... `Model.validate_unique()` will skip validation for that particular constraint.

it is actually `BaseModelForm.validate_unique()` that [causes](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/forms/models.py#L419) the constraint to be skipped.

`Model.validate_unique()` by itself will *not* skip the constraint, unless we explicitly set `exclude=['date']`.

If we validate a `ModelForm` instance, the `date` field with `editable=False` is excluded automatically: The field is excluded from the form [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/forms/models.py#L146), and, as a result, the field is excluded from validation [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/forms/models.py#L321).

Modified the example to illustrate this:

```
NAME = 'bird'
TODAY = timezone.now().date()

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique_for_date='date')
    date = models.DateField(editable=False)

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

class MyModelTests(TransactionTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        MyModel.objects.create(name=NAME, date=TODAY)

    def test_model_validate_name_unique_for_date(self):
        # constraint is NOT skipped if we validate the Model instance directly
        with self.assertRaises(ValidationError) as a:
            MyModel(name=NAME, date=TODAY).validate_unique()
        self.assertIn('Name must be unique for Date date.', a.exception.messages)

    def test_modelform_validate_name_unique_for_date(self):
        # constraint IS skipped if we validate a ModelForm instance
        my_model_form = MyModelForm(data=dict(name=NAME, date=TODAY))
        self.assertTrue(my_model_form.is_valid())
```